# GreenGrass device is registered as an IoT Thing but not as a GreenGrass Core after Fleet Provisioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot-greengrass

After a GreenGrass Fleet Provision, the device is registered in AWS IoT as a Thing, but is not registered as a GreenGrass Core device.
I have a setup on EC2 (with TCP connection enabled) and RPi, both with the same issue, in both cases I get these errors in /greengrass/v2/logs/greengrass.log related to MQTT:

```
EC2 Instance:
2022-06-24T05:22:27.557Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-9) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.IotJobsHelper: No connection available during subscribing to Iot Jobs descriptions topic. Will retry in sometime. {ThingName=ec2_gg_thing_test}
2022-06-24T05:22:35.268Z [ERROR] (pool-2-thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient: Error subscribing. {topic=$aws/things/ec2_gg_thing_test/shadow/name/AWSManagedGreengrassV2Deployment/update/accepted}
2022-06-24T05:22:35.269Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.ShadowDeploymentListener: Caught exception while subscribing to shadow topics, will retry shortly. {}

RPi Zero:
2022-06-24T05:25:20.883Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-11) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.IotJobsHelper: No connection available during subscribing to Iot Jobs descriptions topic. Will retry in sometime. {ThingName=rpiZero}
2022-06-24T05:26:10.037Z [ERROR] (pool-2-thread-10) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient: Error subscribing. {topic=$aws/things/rpiZero/shadow/name/AWSManagedGreengrassV2Deployment/update/accepted}
2022-06-24T05:26:10.043Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-10) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.ShadowDeploymentListener: Caught exception while subscribing to shadow topics, will retry shortly. {}
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

-- edit

Command used:

```
sudo -E java -Droot=/greengrass/v2 -Dlog.store=FILE \
-jar /GreengrassInstaller/lib/Greengrass.jar \
--trusted-plugin /GreengrassInstaller/FleetProvisioningByClaim.jar \
--init-config /GreengrassInstaller/config.yaml \
--component-default-user ggc_user:ggc_group \
--setup-system-service true
```

/GreengrassInstaller/config.yaml

```
---
services:
  aws.greengrass.Nucleus:
    version: "2.5.6"
  aws.greengrass.FleetProvisioningByClaim:
    configuration:
      rootPath: "greengrass/v2"
      awsRegion: "us-west-2"
      iotDataEndpoint: "<data-endpoint>-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
      iotCredentialEndpoint: "<credentials-endpoint>.credentials.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
      iotRoleAlias: "GGProvisionTest_TokenExchange_RoleAlias"
      provisioningTemplate: "GGProvisionTest_Template"
      claimCertificatePath: "greengrass/v2/claim-certs/claim.pem.crt"
      claimCertificatePrivateKeyPath: "greengrass/v2/claim-certs/claim.private.pem.key"
      rootCaPath: "greengrass/v2/AmazonRootCA1.pem"
      templateParameters:
        ThingName: "<thingName>"
        ThingGroupName: "<thingGroup>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this (modified GGv2 to use 443 port). Also, make sure your role and policy are setup correctly:

```
---
services:
  aws.greengrass.Nucleus:
    version: "2.5.6"
    configuration:
      mqtt:
        port: 443
      greengrassDataPlanePort: 443
  aws.greengrass.FleetProvisioningByClaim:
    configuration:
      rootPath: "greengrass/v2"
      awsRegion: "us-west-2"
      iotDataEndpoint: "<data-endpoint>-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
      iotCredentialEndpoint: "<credentials-endpoint>.credentials.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
      iotRoleAlias: "GGProvisionTest_TokenExchange_RoleAlias"
      provisioningTemplate: "GGProvisionTest_Template"
      claimCertificatePath: "greengrass/v2/claim-certs/claim.pem.crt"
      claimCertificatePrivateKeyPath: "greengrass/v2/claim-certs/claim.private.pem.key"
      rootCaPath: "greengrass/v2/AmazonRootCA1.pem"
      templateParameters:
        ThingName: "<thingName>"
        ThingGroupName: "<thingGroup>"
```